# Hibernate Validator custom messages key with class name and field name

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, message, field-names

I've been trying to add custom messages for validation errors for a REST Service managed by Spring MVC within a @Controller class.

The Employee class:

```
public class Employee {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String company;
    ...
}
```

My REST Service:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void add(@RequestBody @Valid Employee employee) {
    employees.add(employee);
}
```

And the validation errors parses

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public @ResponseBody
List<String> validationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (FieldError error : e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
        errors.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
    }

    return errors;
}
```

So I've put a ValidationMessages.properties on the root of my classpath, and I'm not able to get my custom messages with the following key `NotEmpty.employee.company`.

I know there are many ways to do this with a ResourceBundle and error.getCode(), or even with the key `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message`, but I'd like have specific messages to specific field of specific objects.

I also don't want to do this with `@NotEmpty(message = "NotEmpty.employee.company}")`. I want it the simplest.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement your own

```
org.springframework.validation.MessageCodesResolver
```

and then declaring your implementation in the config file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven message-codes-resolver="org.example.YourMessageCodesResolverImpl"/>
```

I'd give it a try, it seems this one is able to build custom error codes like the ones you want:

```
String[]    resolveMessageCodes(String errorCode, String objectName, String field, Class<?> fieldType)
```

The only and *important* thing I'm not sure is whether it'll override the error codes generated by the hibernate validators...

I hope it helps (and works).

Cheers,

Chico.